# Close Lightning Quick Action pop-up on opening another pop-up from that Quick Action

Tags: lightning-aura-components, quickaction, lightning-quickaction

I have a button inside the Quick Action pop up window. On click of that i'm opening new Modal (pop-up) when this pop-up opens i would like to close the main Quick Action pop-up.

If i use `$A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();` then both pop-ups getting closed. How can i close the Quick Action pop-up on opening of another Modal.

EDIT

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.open}">
        <c:newLWC name="{!v.name}"/>
</aura:if>
```

setting v.open to true when button(which is available in the Quick Action pop-up) is clicked. **newLWC** component entire code is inside Modal(pop-up).

Comment: how are you opening the second modal?

Comment: edited question.

Comment: You should open a modal using event. Your problem is that you are rendering your modal as part of the quick-action modal, so when your modal is hidden, so is the all its code, including your fake modal

Comment: Do you have example ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set min-height of new component as higher than the Quick Action modal height.

Otherwise, you can set the height of new component as `style="height: inherit;"` In either of these ways, you can hide the Quick Action modal from users visibility.

Then, you can do all the work in New Modal and then you can navigate to the required page using `$A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject")` or `$A.get("e.force:navigateToURL")` etc.,